# Monitor displays signal out of range until the graphical interface is loaded after installing

Tags: 11.04, command-line, boot, grub2, monitor

When the computer is booting all I get is the error message displayed by the monitor. I need to be able to choose the OS during startup however.

I'm using a 1024x768 on this monitor, though it maxes at 1280x1024 or something like that.

I've tried commenting the `/etc/default/grub` file in the `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` line but that didn't work.

Also, when I press `ctrl + alt + f1-6` to access the cli without the gui I get that error as well. I've read [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/signal-out-of-range-problem-after-ubuntu-11-04-natty-installed) that pressing ctrl + alt + '+' or '-' in the numpad could change the resolution but I get nothing. I've also installed startupmanager as advised in the link. None of the configuration options in it seem to make any difference.

I'm using Xubuntu though I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Nevermind. I edited the resolution to 1024x768 for grub2 and it worked. I don't understand why 640x480 didn't, but it's working so. I was going to put it in the answers but I can't. I'll come back later and do it.

Answer (score 2):

After uncommenting "GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480" in "/etc/default/grub" and saving file you should run "sudo update-grub", worked fine for me.