# Cannot install xubuntu 11.04 because of "signal out of range"

Tags: 10.10, installation, xubuntu

Just grab iso from official site, burnt it on a cd, tried to install, after the first language selection menu, monitor turned black with message: "signal out of range". What can I do, especially, can I do something right there, without burning new iso, because I'm currently out of blank CDs, will I have this kind of problems after the installation? Please Help!

Comment: duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/38264/monitor-displays-signal-out-of-range-until-the-graphical-interface-is-loaded-afte

Comment: @Rinzwind no, that question is about "after installation", I even can't install!

Comment: sorry! you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution based on GUTSY here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=4380153&postcount=8  Yes, I know Gutsy is alot older so this might not even come close to 11.04's install but #10 will always work :-D

edit: #9 is certainly invalid for 11.04. #5 is the one that will tell you if this still works in 11.04. Please report back with the answer ;-)

From that post:

1. First, boot your system with the Ubuntu Live CD.
2. At the Ubuntu boot up screen, make sure that the first item (Start or Install Ubuntu) is active and press F6.
3. Replace the words "quite splash --" with "single" without the quotes and press Enter to continue.
4. Some text messages will flow. When the boot process is complete, you will find yourself logged as root in text mode.
5. When (or if) you reach the text prompt at the end of the boot up process, issue this command: dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg  Select "vesa" as the driver and "1024x768" and “800x600” as the resolutions.
6. Exit the root session either with "exit" or "Ctrl+D".
7. The system will automatically load to the graphical Live CD environment. If not, you can force it manually by entering "startx".
8. If this does not work, then repeat the same steps and select a different low resolution proportional to your screen size.
9. Normally, this step is not necessary, but just for your information; you can also write "nano -w /etc/X11/xorg.conf" or if you are familiar with Vi Editor, "vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf" to edit the resolutions manually in the "xorg.conf" file.
10. Otherwise, the only option you have is to download Ubuntu Alternate CD from:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download

Comment: man, I have brand new iso burnt on cd and windows and fresh empty hard drive on which I want to install ubuntu. Is there any possibility I can use command line during the installation, to be able to issue #5?

Comment: could you please explain step by step what should I do. Currently I'm on installation main screen appearing after language selection (Try.., Install, ... etc), my actions?