# What version of ubuntu can I install and use in the current situation when 11.04 even not installable ("monitor out of range")?

Tags: system-installation

Because of all that problems with 11.04, what ubuntu distribution is it safe to install? Or maybe some other linux distros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10.04 is probably your best bet - it's a long time support release and , as such, it is usually more stable than the latest ones.

Answer (score 1):

I answered the same question today with a 10 step how to here:

[Cannot install xubuntu 11.04 because of "signal out of range"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39248/cannot-install-xubuntu-11-04-because-of-signal-out-of-range/39256#39256)

Please report back if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to boot with some options like `acpi=off`, `noalpic, vga`.